# Por que cada vez que giro meu celular Android da vertical ele executa novamente?

Tags: android

Quando estou fazendo um app eu costumo colocar algumas mensagens de impressão para saber o que está acontecendo, mas percebi que quando estou rodando o app e muda de vertical para paisagem imprime tudo de novo no LogCat, alguém sabe por que isso acontece? Uso System.out.println.

Comment: Ele deve estar entrando novamente no método Oncreate, posta a tela que está com esse problema.

Answer (score 3):

Para conseguir desenvolver com proficiência no Android você precisa compreender os **lifecycles** ( Ciclos de Vida ) dos elementos. Esta é uma característica básica do sistema e domina-la é fundamental.

Quando você gira o seu dispositivo o gerenciador do sistema destrói sua atividade bem como todos os fragmentos e elementos, salva o estado atual ( basicamente as características visuais) e reconstrói tudo do zero. Por essa razão seus LogCats estão sempre exibidos novamente.

Isso significa que neste processo você **irá perder qualquer referência que não tenha sido devidamente salva**. Recomendo que você estude bastante os lifecycles, especialmente das Activities e Fragments, pois eles são levemente diferentes.
Segue um diagrama do **lifecycle de uma atividade** para você ter uma idéia.

Recomendo que você leia este documento [aqui](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). Está em inglês, mas ele é FUNDAMENTAL para compreender o sistema android.

Boa sorte =)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver este problema abra o arquivo AndroidManifest.xml, daí na declaração da sua activity adicione a seguinte linha:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Exemplo:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```